# UIActivityViewController whatsapp always return yes even if user dismiss

Tags: objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I try to share with UIActivityViewController from my app.
but when try to share to'whatsapp' or 'reminders' even if the user clicked dismiss in the completed flag I get YES.

in facebook its work great.

what can be the problem ?

```
- (void)share
{
    NSString *text = @"share test";

    NSArray * activityItems = @[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", text], [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.test.co"]];
    NSArray * applicationActivities = nil;
    NSArray * excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeMessage];

    UIActivityViewController * activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:applicationActivities];
    activityController.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

    [self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];


    [activityController setCompletionWithItemsHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError)
    {
        NSLog(@"The setCompletionWithItemsHandler completed = %i", completed);

        if (completed)
        {

            NSLog(@"The selected activity was %@", activityType);

            if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMail])
            {
                NSLog(@"Mail sended");
            }
            else if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter])
            {
                NSLog(@"Post on twitter, ok!");
            }
            else if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook])
            {
                NSLog(@"Post on facebook, ok!");
            }
            else if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMessage])
            {
                NSLog(@"SMS sended!");
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIActivityViewController completion handler still calls action if user presses cancel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083922/uiactivityviewcontroller-completion-handler-still-calls-action-if-user-presses-c)

Comment: This has been asked before but I agree, it looks like a bug to me.

Comment: it not duplicated becouse in Facebook its work grate and in WhatsApp is always return yes even if user canael or dismiss

Comment: Already sent an email to 'iphone_web@support.whatsapp.com' for fixing this issue. Now waiting for their reply.