# xCode ios Error "completionHandler' is deprecated" in Cardcell.m

Tags: ios, xcode

I get this error : 'completionHandler' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 8.0 - Use completionWithItemsHandler instead.

Here is the code I used -

```
  avc.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed){
        if (completed) {
```

for some reason I get it in Cardcell.m. It makes my build fail.

Here is the [full code](https://pastebin.com/0K3dvuCf) incase you would like a look at it.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083922/uiactivityviewcontroller-completion-handler-still-calls-action-if-user-presses-c

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik so do i use "activityViewController.completionHandler = {(activityType, completed:Bool) in
    if !completed {
        //cancelled
        return
    }" or ? I see they listed the error too "completionHandler is deprecated in iOS 8. For iOS 8, use completionWithItemsHandler. "

Comment: Refer to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller) the `completionHandler` property is deprecated in favour of `completionWithItemsHandler` so you need to adapt the code.